# how to sort two strings with a 4-digit number(year) inside?

Tags: php, sorting

i want to sort two statments year wise so that 1920's statment comes first and then 1930's statment .

First i explode the two strings by (.) and then i used natsort to sort them by year..but it didnt worked. what i have done so far is:

```
<?php

$strn="The Muslim League slowly rose to mass popularity in the **1930s** amid fears of under-representation and neglect of Muslims in politics.The largely non-violent independence struggle led by the Indian Congress engaged millions of protesters in mass campaigns of civil disobedience in the **1920s**";

$result = explode('.',$strn);
natsort($result);

echo $result[0];

echo $result[1];
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Here I just grab the year out of each string and do [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to compare the strings and sort them by the year)

```
usort($arr, function($a, $b){
    preg_match("/\d{4}/", $a, $matches);
    $yearOne = $matches[0];
    preg_match("/\d{4}/", $b, $matches);
    $yearTwo = $matches[0];

    if($yearOne == $yearTwo)
        return 0;
    return $yearOne > $yearTwo ? 1 : -1;
});
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => The largely non-violent independence struggle led by the Indian Congress engaged millions of protesters in mass campaigns of civil disobedience in the **1920s**
    [1] => The Muslim League slowly rose to mass popularity in the **1930s** amid fears of under-representation and neglect of Muslims in politics
)
```

Also if you then want to print it as a string again use:

```
echo implode(".", $strn);
```

Comment: what is $a, $b ? isnt it should be $strn?
ps: i am not getting the output you got..

Comment: @candycrush `$a` and `$b` are elements of `$strn` which gets compared and sorted(ps: http://3v4l.org/JTAr2 <-- Here is an example of the code to compare it how you use it, it should work :)

Comment: @candycrush ^ See the link in the last comment there is a link. Otherwise post a pastebin or so how you use the code.

Comment: superb...perfect...thank you so much for the time and effort. you are so nice. :)